# How to resolve Scala 2.10.x flatten issue

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, flatten

In Scala 2.10.3, I see this problem.

```scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.


scala> val list = List(1, 2, List(5, 6))
list: List[Any] = List(1, 2, List(5, 6))

scala> list.flatten
<console>:9: error: No implicit view available from Any => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].
           list.flatten
                ^
```

How do I resolve this issue?

My current workaround is define my own flat function.

```scala
def flat(list: List[Any]): List[Any] = list flatten {
  case i: List[Any] => flat(i)
  case e => List(e)
}

scala> flat(list)
res2: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 12):

Well this is not an Issue with `Scala 2.10.3` but with rather every version since `2.8.0` when `flatten` was introduced. And it is behaving perfectly as it should:

[flatten](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate) basically does:

> Converts this collection of traversable collections into a collection
>   formed by the elements of these traversable collections.

So in short for your type `A` need to have a function `A => GenTraversableOnce` which can help you traverse them. In your case:

```
scala> val x = List(1, 2, List(3, 4))
x: List[Any] = List(1, 2, List(3, 4))
```

`x` is of type `List[Any]` and it is impossible to have a generic function for `Any` type as anyone and everyone will have their own definition. What you could instead do is:
(Will work for multiple Nested Lists also):

```
def flatten(ls: List[Any]): List[Any] = ls flatMap {
  case i: List[_] => flatten(i)
  case e => List(e)
}

val k = List(1, List(2, 3), List(List(List(List(4)), List(5)), List(6, 7)), 8)
flatten(k)
```

It prints `List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)`

Answer (score 6):

Your solution works.  But, in general, having a `List[Any]` seems like an undesirable situation.  `Any` should be avoided since it's really circumventing the nice things that the type checker does for you.

A better solution might be to use a specially designed class hierarchy:

```
sealed trait Tree {
  def flatten: List[Int]
}

case class Node(children: List[Tree]) extends Tree {
  def flatten = children.flatMap(_.flatten)
}

case class Leaf(n: Int) extends Tree {
  def flatten = List(n)
}
```

Then:

```
val t = Node(List(Leaf(1), Leaf(2), Node(List(Leaf(5), Leaf(6)))))
t.flatten // List(1, 2, 5, 6)
```

And you could also do:

```
def flat(t: Tree): List[Int] = t match {
  case Node(children) => children.flatMap(c => flat(c))
  case Leaf(n) => List(n)
}
```

So:

```
flat(t) // List(1, 2, 5, 6)
```

Comment: So, I guess that I have write my own flat. Scala's flatten doesn't work anymore

Comment: Scala's flatten works just fine; however, it's not possible to flatten a `List[Any]` because the type checker has no idea whether `Any` is traversable.

Comment: Just because Scala lets you omit type declarations, doesn't mean it's a dynamic language. You should resist the urge to write Scala code as you would Python.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that there is no *implicit* way to do the flattening you want: `(Any => List[Any])`.

You could feed a modified version of your `flat` function into `flatten` to achieve the effect you want:

```
val x = List(1, 2, List(3, 4))

def flat2(any: Any): List[Any] =
  any match {
    case i: List[_] => i
    case _ => List(any)
  }

x.flatten(flat2)
```